# Modify value before using in SQL where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a way that I can modify a value in my model before it goes to MySQL in the `WHERE` clause?

Specifically, I'm working with phone numbers, and to ensure user privacy, I'm only storing SHA256 hashed phone numbers in the DB. **But**, I want to be able to act on the model as if it's not hashed.

For example:

```
def phone_number=(number)
    write_attribute(:phone_number, OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', 'salt', number))
end
```

This lets me save the raw phone number and have it auto-hashed. But is there a way I can do

```
PhoneNumbers.where(phone_number: '555-1234')
```

and have `'555-1234'` get hashed before it gets translated into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom Serializer solved my use case for this perfectly!

```
# lib/serializers/phone_hash_serializer.rb
class PhoneHashSerializer
  def self.load(value)
    value.to_s
  end

  def self.dump(value)
    value = value.to_s
    if value.start_with? 'hashed!'
      value
    else
      # Rails serializer's do not handle one-way hashing well, as the value ends up getting
      # getting dumped/hashed twice (once on the type-cast, then again before storing to DB).
      # So, we "tag" the value as "hashed!" to ensure we don't double hash since search's
      # only get hashed once, and would therefore never match the DB value
      'hashed!' + hash_string(value)
    end
  end

  private

  def self.hash_string(value)
    OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', 'hash_salt', value)
  end
end


# models/phone_number.rb
require 'serializers/phone_hash_serializer'
...
serialize :phone_number, PhoneHashSerializer
...
```

I used http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-write-custom-serializer-for-activerecord-number-serialize/ as my muse. Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 3):

Check this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html, specially the Creating Custom Types title.

You define a custom type and set that as the type of your attribute. You define a "serialize" method that converts your value to use SQL statements.

From the docs:

```
class Money < Struct.new(:amount, :currency)
end

class MoneyType < Type::Value
  def initialize(currency_converter:)
    @currency_converter = currency_converter
  end

  # value will be the result of +deserialize+ or
  # +cast+. Assumed to be an instance of +Money+ in
  # this case.
  def serialize(value)
    value_in_bitcoins = @currency_converter.convert_to_bitcoins(value)
    value_in_bitcoins.amount
  end
end

# config/initializers/types.rb
ActiveRecord::Type.register(:money, MoneyType)

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  currency_converter = ConversionRatesFromTheInternet.new
  attribute :price_in_bitcoins, :money, currency_converter: currency_converter
end

Product.where(price_in_bitcoins: Money.new(5, "USD"))
# => SELECT * FROM products WHERE price_in_bitcoins = 0.02230

Product.where(price_in_bitcoins: Money.new(5, "GBP"))
# => SELECT * FROM products WHERE price_in_bitcoins = 0.03412
```

As you can see, the where method receives a Money object, but the SQL statement has a decimal value.

Comment: I like the concept, however it didn't end up working out for me. Turns out a custom Serializer is what I needed